# Make jQuery library available in Facebook.com domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, dom, inject

Alright. I'm just trying to play with jQuery library within `Facebook.com` DOM elements. Actually, Facebook is not using `jQuery`. So I've tried to inject below `JS` snippet to make `jQuery` available for the page.

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

setTimeout(function () {
       $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    }, 5000);
```

But, I'm not able to use any of the 'jQuery' functionalities in any browsers.  `$` is already defined from facebook & I'm getting error for variables like `jQuery`, `$jq`. The above code works well with other sites including `Google.com`.

In Chrome, It gives the following error on `facebook.com` as well .

> Refused to load the script
>   'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
>   *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.akamaihd.net *.atlassolutions.com
>   blob: chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl".

Anyone has came across this problem? Please share. Thanks in Advance.

**Note** : I can make use of `jQuery` functionalities by pasting & executing entire code into console but I need to know what causing this issue & any alternate solution (If any).

Comment: _`jQuery`, `$jq` & `$` is already defined from facebook_...then why you need to append another lib?

Comment: @Jai: That _objects_ by those names exist, does not necessarily mean that jQuery is embedded. They could have simply created those objects themselves, to try and _prevent_ people from using jQuery on their site. (As an additional measure to protect people from what lonesomeday said in their answer, if the browser perhaps doesn’t support CSP yet.)

Comment: @Jai What I meant, I can't use `jQuery` `$` alias since `$` was already declared within Facebook JS code & Neither `jQuery` nor my defined varibale `$jq` is not working even after execution of that snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're facing is the Content Security Policy header. This allows the use of scripts only from whitelisted sites that are supplied in the HTTP header for the page itself. You can read more about how this works on [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/).

There is no way around this policy: it is used by Facebook to prevent people being persuaded (see "Social engineering") to execute arbitrary Javascript code that gives other people access to their account.

The best solution is not to use jQuery libraries but to use native Javascript to do your manipulation.

Comment: Thanks. Native JavaScript code will be much lengthier which is why I opted to use jQuery to fiddle with. So the only solution is to paste & execute `jQuery` source into the Console?

Comment: Yeah, or implement your own helper functions to do what you need. @JensonMJohn

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the [content of the library](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js) and paste it into the facebook console.